# How to use local js or css file while using webview_flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-plugin

This question is for webview_flutter plug-in. (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

I have manage to load local .html file, however .js file and .css include as a part of html code is not working.

This is working well at Native Android & Native iOS App.

I think this is one of the basic feature in order to support html view.

Is webview_flutter is not supported js & css include ?

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think that it's not supported? It works just like in any browser: you can provide either relative or absolute path to your JS/CSS files. Just don't forget to set `javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted` to allow javascript code execution. Here's my example of creating HTML page with JS/CSS files:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
```

```dart
  Future<void> _showHtml() async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    final htmlPath = join(tempDir.path, 'page.html');
    final cssPath = join(tempDir.path, 'css.css');
    final jsPath = join(tempDir.path, 'js.js');

    File(htmlPath).writeAsStringSync('<html><head><link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "$cssPath" /><script src="$jsPath"></script></head><body><div>Test</div></body></html>');
    File(cssPath).writeAsStringSync('div {background:green;}');
    File(jsPath).writeAsStringSync('document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"});');

    setState(() {
      uri = Uri(scheme: 'file', path: htmlPath);
    });
  }
```

```dart
  child: uri != null ? WebView(
    initialUrl: uri.toString(),
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) => c = controller,
  ) : Container()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick update with example, however I am still confused on how to use js library with html page. Actually, I want like to use Jquery & Bootstrap css along with html. Is this possible ??

Comment: @DhavalPatel There are no reasons for that to be impossible. I showed you simple example. In your case you'll have multiple js/css files (or one minified). Just make sure you have correct paths to your files in your HTML. If you don't know how to use jquery/bootstrap, you should probably look in some tutorials. As I said - WebView is almost no different from regular browser.